# Cross domain REST using Ajax in Dojo

Tags: ajax, rest, dojo

I have using dojo.xhrPost method in Dojo and trying to call url  from different domain server REST services. I have facing problem in cross-domain.

I have getting ERROR ::: “ RequestError: Unable to load https://core.dev.moxynetwork.com/rest/authservice/authuser status: 0”

Please help me.

Regards&Thanks,
Vijayalaxmi

Answer (score 1):

dojo.xhrPost is deprecated and will be removed.

Use dojo/request/script with dojo 1.9 :

```
require(['dojo','dojo/ready','dojo/_base/lang','dojo/_base/array', 'dojo/request/script' ],
    function(dojo, ready, lang, array, script){
        ready(function(){
            script.get('ENTER-YOUR-URL.com',{jsonp: "callback"}).then(function(resJson){
                console.log(resJson);
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) to manage cross domain calls. Both are techniques for the REST API that is nothing you can do on the client side.